# How To Find Elements By Id in Angular Directive Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I have a directive that renders the following html in a unit test:

```
<div id="published-envs">
    <strong>Published to</strong>
    <!-- ngRepeat: env in fundConfigurationVersion.publicationEnvironments --><div data-ng-repeat="env in fundConfigurationVersion.publicationEnvironments" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            QA (Jan 29, 2015)
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: env in publicationEnvironments --><div data-ng-repeat="env in publicationEnvironments" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            PROD (Jan 30, 2015)
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: env in publicationEnvironments -->
</div>
```

I am trying to get a hold of the `<div id="published-envs">` and assert that it has two child `<div>`'s in it.

I have tried the following but it does not work:
`var environments = element.find('#published-envs'); //comes back empty`

What is the correct way to find elements by id in an angular unit test?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular Element Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), `.find()`

> Limited to lookups by tag name

Try

```
var environments = angular.element(document.getElementById('published-envs')).find('div');
```

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v07uy0gf/)

### Edit

For compiled markup, it's essentially the same, just inject the `$compile` service and use as follows

```
var comipledEnvironments = $compile(angular.element('<div id="published-envs"><div></div><div></div></div>'))($scope).find('div')

console.log(comipledEnvironments); // 2 <div>'s
```

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v98ssudo/)

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  I am compiling an html snippet in the unit test as follows:      `var element = angular.element('<div data-fund-config-version data-version-data="fundConfigurationVersion"></div>');
      element = compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();`  In this context, I don't think that document includes the compiled html.  I tried logging the document and didn't see the html rendered by the directive.

Comment: it should be `var comipledEnvironments = ($compile(angular.element('<div id="published-envs"><div></div><div></div></div>'))($scope)).find('div')`